# Is it possible to save and deploy a node without closing the editor window on Node-RED?

Tags: node-red

Let's say I'm modifying a function or a template node on Node-RED like the following:

[image]

I know the default shortcut for deploying the flow is `ctrl-5`. However, I'd like to use a shortcut to save the changes that I made on the function node without closing it (the same behavior of clicking in `done` but without clicking on it and without closing the editor). Is there any shortcut that I can configure to make it possible on Node-RED?

---

My idea is to use a shortcut to save my changes and then using `ctrl-5` to deploy the flow... The reason why this would be useful for me is that sometimes when I have hundreds of lines of code inside a function or template node it becomes bothersome to close the editor and lose the line that I was editing (it always goes back to line 1 after reopening it)

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible. Changes are not written back to the editor's internal representation of the node until the edit dialog is closed.

This may be something we improve in the future.